# Ember-cli specify node.js debug port

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

To use node.js remote debugging, I could set a debug port to 8001 when starting the server with `node --debug=8001 app.js`. How can I do this using ember-cli? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that you can call ember through node cli: `node --debug=4202 ./node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember server`